# Join same table with different column

Tags: sql, join, left-join, right-join

Hi This may be a stupid question but I have a scenario where my columns tl1,tl2 and tl3 refers to column id table structure is below,

```
id | name | email | tl1 | tl1 | tl3 |
1  | xyz  |x@g.com| null|  1  | 2   |
======================================
2  | abc  |z@g.com| null|  1  | 3   |
======================================
3  | def  |d@g.com| 1   |  2  |  4  |
```

SO need to write a query to get the name of tl1,tl2 and tl3,

like below

```
id | name | email | tl1 | tl1 | tl3 |
1  | xyz  |x@g.com| null| xyz | abc |
======================================
2  | abc  |z@g.com| null| xyz  | def|
======================================
3  | def  |d@g.com| xyz |  abc | ghi |
```

I am not able to create query for this scenario, I actually created one but not getting unique records

This is the query which I tried

```
select distinct a.branch_code,a.email,a.partner_name,a.role_assigned,a.category,b.partner_name as tl1,
c.partner_name as tl2,d.partner_name as tl3
 from branch_master as a
 left join  branch_master  as b on b.tl1 = a.branch_code
 left join  branch_master as c on c.tl2 = a.branch_code
 left join  branch_master as d on d.tl3 = a.branch_code
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the queries that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to left join the table 3 times with itself:

```
select
  t.id, t.name, t.email,
  t1.name name1, t2.name name2, t3.name name3
from tablename t
left join tablename t1 on t1.id = t.tl1
left join tablename t2 on t2.id = t.tl2
left join tablename t2 on t3.id = t.tl3
```

Comment: Thanks this work, can you explain why my query is not working

Comment: I can't tell. Some column names are different.

Comment: And why do you use distinct?

Comment: because my query was returning duplicate data so thought by putting the distinct gives me correct result.

Comment: The only different between your and my query is this part
```left join  branch_master  as b on b.branch_code = a.tl1
 left join  branch_master as c on c.branch_code = a.tl2
 left join  branch_master as d on d.branch_code = a.tl3 ```
dont know why my query gives me wrong data

Comment: You must have modified my query to your actual table and column names. There you can see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is generally a bad data format -- typically, you want the values in different tables.  There are some cases where it might make sense to have the data across columns -- for instance, if role are different:  `submitted_by`, `processed_by`, `approved_by`.  But generally, you want a junction/association table.

The solution to your problem, though, is multiple left joins:

```
select t.*, t1.email as email1, t2.email as email2, t2.email as email3
from t left join
     t t1
     on t1.tl1 = t.id left join
     t t2
     on t2.tl2 = t.id left join
     t t3
     on t3.tl3 = t.id;
```

Comment: This give the duplicate data